# Sub-folders for Controllers without Areas

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

I'm trying to organize the Controllers into sub-folders so that the request would look like:

```
<domain>/Account/Home
<domain>/Client/Home
<domain>/Vendor/Home
```

And have the controllers folder like:

```
Controllers\Account\HomeController
Controllers\Vendor\HomeController
Controllers\Client\HomeController
```

I am familiar with the Areas in MVC but I prefer not to use that. If there's an alternative way to register routes to use sub-folders on the controllers, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Areas?  This is one of the reasons why they exist.  The alternative would be to add a ton of routes to the RouteCollection (RouteCollection.MapRoute).

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx